# Which one is a greater in quantity: Number System

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, arithmetic

$x$ and $y$ are non-negative integers.

Then which one is greater or both are equal:
$$
\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} \text{ or } \sqrt{x+y}?
$$

Comment: Have you looked at any examples at all?

Answer (score 4):

$\sqrt x+\sqrt y$ will be $\ge\sqrt{x+y}$

iff $(\sqrt x+\sqrt y)^2\ge (\sqrt{x+y})^2$

iff $x+y+2\sqrt{xy}\ge x+y$

if $\sqrt{xy}\ge 0$ which is true

The equality occurs if at least one of $x,y$ is $0$

Comment: Note: this same proof works for any non-negative reals (not just integers).

Comment: @vadim123, thanks for pointing out. I realized it, but missed to mention it in the answer